# Issues with DNS & SMTP with my Domain while setting webmail on my premises

Tags: smtp, email-server, nslookup, webmail

My domain is *worldlightingservice.com*

I've been able to work out a lot of issues that I had from searching on https://mxtoolbox.com/ (A records, dns, smtp, blacklist and many others) but I'm not able to work out the reverse DNS lookup. I just can't figure this out.

My .com domain is hosted in Globat and there I have everything pointing to my server on my premises. When I do the lookup on *worldlightingservice.com* it points to my IP where I have the mail server, which I think is ok. But when I do a lookup on the IP it gets to my hostname assigned by my ISP.

nslookup 186.136.111.143
143.111.136.186.in-addr.arpa    name = **143-111-136-186.fibertel.com.ar.**

How can I change this?
Do I have to work it out with my ISP?

Answer (score 1):

> when i do a lookup on the ip it gets to my hostname assigned by my isp

Right. The ISP manages the reverse lookup zone for the ip address space they've been assigned.

> How can i change this? do i have to work it out with my isp?

Yes. You'll need to contact them and ask if they'll create the PTR record for you that you wish to have.